# Issues passing dynamodb response data to callback function

Tags: javascript, node.js, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

Friends, I've been banging my head against my desk. I'm writing an Alexa+Lambda+Dynamodb string of actions/events. The issue comes in my Lambda Node.JS. I have the function getChores in which I'm trying to run a simple getItem() to pull just a sample entry in a dynamodb, however I can ONLY access the data returned in the Else statement but I need to pass it via the callback in speechOutput. Any assistance you can provide would be greatly appreciated!

```
function getChores(callback) {
    sessionAttributes = {};

    var params = {
        TableName: 'Chores',
        Key: {
            'chore': {
                S: 'Clean up toys'
            },
        }
    };

    // Call DynamoDB to read the item from the table
    var results = ddb.getItem(params, function(err, data) {
        if (err) {
            console.log("Error", err);
        } else {
            //CAN ONLY ACCESS HERE!
            console.log("Success", data.Item);
            speechOutput = data.Item.chore.S;
            console.log(data.Item.chore.S);
            console.log(speechOutput);
        }

    });

    console.log(results);

    //Get card title from data
    const cardTitle = "Chore"

    //Get output from data
    //const speechOutput = element.chore;
    // If the user either does not reply to the welcome message or says something that is not
    // understood, they will be prompted again with this text.
    const repromptText = '';
    const shouldEndSession = false;
    callback(sessionAttributes,
        buildSpeechletResponse(cardTitle, speechOutput, repromptText, shouldEndSession));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like ddb.getItem is an async method. You need to call the callback method 'callback' inside the else block.